# Can't capture the output of git pull command in a variable

Tags: bash, variable, read

I run `git -C /another-directory pull` and I get this error:

> Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/main'
> from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.

Now I want to get that response in a variable.

I [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12675950/811785) `read Result < <(git -C /another-directory pull)` and then I ran `echo $Result` and it's empty.

I also tried `git -C /another-directory pull | read Result` and again, it's empty.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

That's output on standard error, not standard output.

To capture both stdout and stderr:

```
Result=$(git ... 2>&1)
```

To capture only stderr while discarding stdout:

```
Result=$(git ... 2>&1 > /dev/null)
```

To capture only stderr while leaving stdout alone:

```
{ Result=$(git ... 2>&1 >&3 3>&-); } 3>&1
```

`read` is the command to *read words* from *one* logical line (physical lines possibly continued using trailing backslashes).

To read one line into a variable, [you use `IFS= read -r line`](/q/209123).

So here, to read the first line of the standard error of `git`, you could do:

```
IFS= read -r Result < <(git ... 2>&1 > /dev/null)
```

But that has several drawbacks:

- you lose the exit status of `git`. That command will succeed if `read` succeed, that is if it manages to read one full line
- as `read` will stop reading and exit after the first line, `git`'s stderr will become a broken pipe so could end up being killed if it prints more errors.

To get only the first line while still not breaking `git`'s stderr pipe and preserving its exit status, you could do:

```
Result=$(
  set -o pipefail
  git ... 2>&1 > /dev/null | sed '1!d'
)
```

Note that the syntax to print the contents of a variable is `printf '%s\n' "$var`, not <strike>`echo $var`</strike>. See also `typeset -p var` in Korn-like shells to print its definition.

Comment: I guess my mind is tired or locked to see this simple thing. I had the knowledge of stdout and stderr, but I could not use that knowledge here. Thank you so much.